# Literal character in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to compile my C# code. I was parsing a string by "....",

```
string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { '....' }, 2);
```

Then I got an error:

> Too many characters in character literal

The line looks like this:

```
abc....  starting word in english
```

I think that I need to convert `....` to `=`. Then everything would work fine. Is there any other way?

Comment: This makes no sense: "i thing that i need to convert .... to = then everything is work fine. are any other good idea you know ?" Care to have another go at explaining what you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx) method:

```
string[] parts = line.Split("....", 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: yes, and the import point is: if you have more than one character in your "delimiters" string as first parameter to `.Split()`, use the double quotes `"....."` rather than single quotes `'....'`

Comment: @steven - it works fine. Darin's example is correct, make sure you're using double quotes `"` and NOT single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 5):

You can only split by `char` by passing a single character: `'.'`.

Split using string instead:

```
string[] parts = line.Split("....", 2);
```